# Cascading select in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, jquery, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-code-first

I want to implement a cascading select between Countries and Cities, where both inherit from a abstract class GeographicBoundary, implementing Table Per Hierarchy (TPH) of EF Core feature. To accomplish it I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.x, EF Core Code-first. But I couldn't implement.

I tried using Json returned from the Controller Action to JQuery/Ajax but with no success.

//SUPER CLASS

```
public abstract class GeographicBoundary  {
    public int GeographicBoundaryId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

//COUNTRY

```
public class Country : GeographicBoundary
    {

    }
```

//CITY

```
public class City : GeographicBoundary
{

    public Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

//CODE IN THE VIEW

```
            @*COUNTRY*@
            <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
                <div class="input-field col s12 m6 offset-m3">
                    <select asp-for="CountryId" asp-items=@ViewBag.Countries>
                    </select>
                    <label>B1 - País</label>
                    <span asp-validation-for="CountryId" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            @*CITIES*@
            <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
                <div class="input-field col s12 m6 offset-m3">
                    <select asp-for="ProvinceId" asp-items="@(new SelectList("", "GeographicBoundaryId", "Name"))"></select>
                    <label>B2 - Cidades</label>
                    <span asp-validation-for="CityId" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

//ViewModel Fileds

```
public int CityId

public int CountryId
```

//MY CONTROLLER

```
public JsonResult GetProvinces(int countryId)
{
    var provinces = _geographicBoundaryManager.GetProvincesByCountryId(countryId).ToList();

    provinces.Insert(0, new Province { GeographicBoundaryId = 0, Name = "SELEECIONAR" });

    return Json(provinces);
}
```

//JS code

```
@section ScriptPage
    {
<script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script>$("#GeographicBoundaryId").change(function () {
        $.get("/Home/GetProvinces", { GeographicBoundaryId: $("#GeographicBoundaryId").val() }, function (data) {
            $("GeographicBoundaryId").empty();
            $.each(data, function (i, row) {
    < !--$("#GeographicBoundaryId").append("<option value='" + data[i].districtId + "'>" + data[i].name + "</option>")-->
                    $("#GeographicBoundaryId").append("<option value='" + row.geographicboundaryId + "'>" + row.name + "</option>")
            });
        });
    })</script>

}
```

Only Countries dropbox works.
Cities dropbox disappear!

Comment: It seems that do not set id attribute for the two dropdown list.You need to populate second dropdownlist who has different id using the returned data.However you use the same id `GeographicBoundaryId` in your js code

Comment: Hello @XingZou! As you should see I use the same Id `GeographicBoundaryId` because both (City and Country) classes use the same property inherited from `GeographicBoundary` super class. EF core doesn't allow to specify Id property on classes that inherit from one where has Id already.

Comment: Hello, what i mean is that the js code `$("#GeographicBoundaryId").change(function () `, I do not see the id for the <select id="GeographicBoundaryId"`.